# Drag and Drop not working with over flow auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello friends i  m trying to make drag and drop functionality on my page but i have facing some problem . u can download my files [here](http://www.cleversoftwares.com/demo/drag/drag_and_drop.zip) the problem is when you open index2.html its working perfect with css

```
#leftColumn{
        width:300px;
        float:left;     
    }
```

But when i add some css on id leftColumn in index.html

```
#leftColumn{
        width:300px;
        float:left;
        height:100px;
        overflow:auto;

    }
```

its stop working perfectly as u can see in the file that in index,html the left side dragable boxes not moving with mouse please help .

Thanks

Comment: Don't include zip files, no one will open them. go to http://jsfiddle.net and place your code appropriately(scripts in script section, html in html section, css in css section, the 'result' will be propagated when you click 'run' at the top.)

Comment: if you dont want to download the zip file then u can see both file live here the first file working perfectly link is http://www.cleversoftwares.com/demo/drag/index2.html and second file http://www.cleversoftwares.com/demo/drag/

Comment: use jsfiddle , so people can play with your code live too and change it directly.

Comment: hello freinds here the link on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/82jue/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need to subtract ".scrollTop" from the childrens parent you are grabbing

EDIT:

in **js/drag-drop-custom.js**

**row 533 I changed**
    this.dragObjCloneArray[this.numericIdToBeDragged].style.top = dhtmlSuiteCommonObj.getTopPos(this.dragDropSourcesArray[this.numericIdToBeDragged][0]) + 'px';
**-to-**
    this.dragObjCloneArray[this.numericIdToBeDragged].style.top = dhtmlSuiteCommonObj.getTopPos(this.dragDropSourcesArray[this.numericIdToBeDragged][0]) **- this.dragObjCloneArray[this.numericIdToBeDragged].parentNode.scrollTop** + 'px';


**row 597 I changed**
    dragObj.style.top = topPos + 'px'; 
**-to-**
    dragObj.style.top = topPos **- dragObj.parentNode.scrollTop** + 'px';

**row 670 I changed**
    var targetY = dhtmlSuiteCommonObj.getTopPos(referenceToDragDropObject.dragDropSourcesArray[numId][0]);
**-to-**
    var targetY = dhtmlSuiteCommonObj.getTopPos(referenceToDragDropObject.dragDropSourcesArray[numId][0]) **- this.dragObjCloneArray[numId].parentNode.scrollTop**;

Now it is working fine in your example, but this is **only** for the **vertical problem**, if you are ever going to have it scrollable horizontally then you'll have to do the same for scrollLeft. And if you need help with that then I'm sorry to tell you that this is too advanced for you.

Comment: Hello harry . how to subtract ".scrollTop" . i was worked on it but its stop working . please share your experience

Thanks